# Ubuntu Eclipse Photon with PDT editor rendering problem

Tags: 16.04, eclipse

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 x64 on Lenovo G560 computer that has Intel i5 2.66 ghz, 8gb ram, Nvidia g310m 512mb video card. I'm using Nvidia Driver Version 340.102.

I installed Eclipse Photon with PDT and sometimes editor wrong rendering. Probably this is an opengl problem but I was use Eclipse Neon and it hasn't like this error. The scenario is that: I'm pushing CTRL+D (Delete line) and wrong rendering. After this time I push CTRL+S (Save) and rendering problem is fixing. I don't want wrong rendering when I push CTRL+D becouse this is breaking my motivation when I coding. Screenshots are here:

Wrong rendering:
[image]

After I save editor rendering is fix.
[image]

How to avoid this problem? Thanks for your comments.